# 3B+ Raspbian video playback slow

Tags: video

Just set up a brand new little system but when I try to play back videos they don't quite play at the right speed. It wouldn't be noticeable except that it makes the audio just a little flat- sounds really weird.

I was originally playing them back in Kodi, where as well as being slow it frequently skips little bits of video (and the associated audio). I tested this with omxplayer from the command line, and while the skipping doesn't happen, it still plays slowly. During playback the CPU Monitor stays down at 0% or 1%, so it doesn't seem to be taxing the system unduly.

The videos are being played back from a SanDisk USB 3 flash drive (I'm aware that the Pi doesn't do USB 3, just pointing out that the drive can cope with the speed), and I've tested it in a USB 2 port on my PC and they play back fine there with VLC. I also copied one video onto the OS SD card and it also plays back slowly from there too.

The videos are h.264 with AAC audio - downloaded directly from YouTube.

What can I check/change to try and get it working?

Comment: check the bitrate and codec information for the videos (in a windows pc, you can use something like "mediainfo" .. or maybe even VLC has a properties function to show such details

Comment: I'm seeing 3109kb/s "input bitrate". H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (avc1). Resolution 1280x720 at 23.976fps.

Also happens with another video which is 1648kb/s, 624x352 at 25fps and identical codec.